# What is the propeller phase of a pulsar?

Tags: astrophysics, pulsars

I am studying [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/astro-ph/9912228.pdf) paper:

> Isolated thermal neutron stars, soft gamma-ray repeaters and anomalous
>   X-ray pulsars:  propellers and early accretors with conventional
>   magnetic fields?

arxiv:astro-ph/9912228

It talks about the propeller phase of a pulsar: what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have found the answer in the paper Illarionov & Sunyaev 1975 A&A 39,185:

[image]

So the propeller phase is the second phase of the life of a pulsar in which the magnetosphere of the star prevents the accretion of matter onto the star